Can I hit an API endpoint directly from an SQS message with AWS Lambda. i am working on amazon sp api notification
I'm currently working on integrating with the Amazon Selling Partner API (SP-API) to handle order change notifications more efficiently, avoiding the need for frequent polling.
I've successfully configured an SQS queue with the Amazon seller account to receive these order change notifications. Now, I’m at the stage where I need to forward these notifications to my application.
Initially, I considered using Amazon SNS to create an HTTPS endpoint to receive the notifications. However, I’ve realized that this approach might not be the most efficient or straightforward for my needs.
Could you provide guidance on the best method to send these SQS notifications directly to my application? I want to ensure I'm following best practices and leveraging the most effective solution.

Before I begin, SQS only supports short polling and long polling (so not pushing). But it works with events which lets the destination to know when to poll! So when you use Lambda integration and Lambda just get invoked and consume the message, it is actually all based on events and the lambda is still polling messages.
Now, the question of how to get the messages to your application:

Outside AWS: Your best bet is to call the application API. The most flexible options to call the API is through a Lambda function.
Inside AWS: You have plenty of options to integrate with different services. You can use Amazon EventBridge to catch the event (modify it if you like) and then send to the many available targets with a rules.

